# Add 1 to a specific alphanumeric row of a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to R, so I'd greatly appreciate your help!

This is my current dataframe named "track_data"

[image]

What I"m trying to do is to change row 11 under class to "T43", row 12 to "T44"
also trying to do the same for all the combinations classes, so: row 13 to "T45", row 14 to "T46" and row 15 to "T47"

what I tried doing is to find which classes are combinations classes and identify the unique vectors:

```
#Change Class to appropriate names
a <- which(nchar(track_data$Class) > 3)
b <- unique(track_data$Class[a])
#T43/44
 for (r in a)
  if(track_data$Class[r] == b[1]){
  print(paste("Row", r))
  for (class in 1:r) 
   track_data$Class[r] <- substr(track_data$Class[r],1,3)
  }
```

And I would repeat it for the other items of b, which are "T45-47" and "T53/54"

This gives me:

[image]

Now I just need to basically find a row that is duplicated, and +1 to the Class, but I keep getting errors because I need to add the "T" as well.

If there is an easier/ more efficient way of accomplishing my task, please let me know!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Change Class to appropriate names
a <- which(nchar(field_data$Class) > 3)
previous <- ""
increment <- 0
for (r in a){
 print(paste(r))
 print(paste(previous))
 print(paste(field_data$Class[r]))
 if (previous != field_data$Class[r]){
  result <- str_match(field_data$Class[r],"([T|F])([0-9]+)")
  print(paste(result))
  t_or_f <- result[2]
  number <- as.integer(result[3])
  previous <- field_data$Class[r]
  field_data$Class[r] <- paste(t_or_f, number, sep = "")
  increment <- 0
 } else {
 increment <- increment + 1
 field_data$Class[r] <- paste(t_or_f, number + increment, sep = "")
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
track_data %>%
    group_by(Class) %>% 
    mutate(Class2 = if(n() > 1) str_c("T", 
      unlist(map(str_extract_all(str_remove(first(Class),
        "T"), "\\d+"),
        ~
            seq(as.numeric(.x[1]), as.numeric(.x[2]), by = 1)))) else Class) %>%
       ungroup %>% 
       mutate(Class = Class2, Class2 = NULL)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 1
  Class
  <chr>
1 T11  
2 T36  
3 T42  
4 T43  
5 T44  
6 T45  
7 T46  
8 T47
```

#### data

```
track_data <- structure(list(Class = c("T11", "T36", "T42", "T43/44", "T43/44", 
"T45-47", "T45-47", "T45-47")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```